# Need help calculating wins and losses from points scored

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a website in php to log ping pong scores for my school, and currently the player who wins will log the `WinnerID, LoserID, PointsFor, PointsAgainst`. I have two tables with the following relationships.

Table: users

- user_ID (PK)
- username
- Elo

Table: games

- game_id (PK)
- WinnerID (FK)
- LoserID (FK)
- PointsFor
- PointsAgainst

My insert statement in the php file is:

```
INSERT INTO games(WinnerID,LoserID,PointsFor,PointsAgainst) VALUES('$Winner_ID','$Loser_ID','$userscore','$oppscore')"
```

Here is what I have tried, but it doesn't display the scores correctly.

```
SELECT min(u.username) 'Username', COUNT(g.WinnerID) 'Wins', sum(g.PointsFor) 'Points For', sum(g.PointsAgainst) 'Points Against', u.Elo 'Ranking' 
from games g 
LEFT JOIN users u 
on g.WinnerID = u.user_id 
Group by g.WinnerID
```

[image: This is the select statement output]

As you can see by the image above, the points for and points against totals don't add up. Currently, it only displays the stats for whoever was winner. Meaning if PlayerA wins 21-5, it will show up from the select statement, but PlayerB will not show a score of 5-21. Any help is appreciated.

PHP code for page to enter scores:

```
if(isset($_POST['btn-post']))
{
    $opponent = $_POST["opponent"];
    //$opponent = array_key_exists('opponent', $_POST) ? $_POST['opponent'] : false;

    $userscore = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userscore']);
    $oppscore = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['oppscore']);

    if($userscore != $oppscore)
    {
        if($userscore > $oppscore)
        {
            $Winner_ID = $_SESSION['user'];
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE username = '".$opponent."'");
            $result = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die(mysql_error());
            $Loser_ID = $result['user_id'];

            $query1 = mysql_query("SELECT Elo FROM users WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']);
            $result1 = mysql_fetch_array($query1) or die(mysql_error());
            $winnerRating = $result1['Elo'];

            $query2 = mysql_query("SELECT Elo FROM users WHERE user_id=".$Loser_ID);
            $result2 = mysql_fetch_array($query2) or die(mysql_error());
            $loserRating = $result1['Elo'];

            $rating = new Rating($winnerRating, $loserRating, 1, 0);            
            $results = $rating->getNewRatings();

            if(mysql_query("UPDATE users SET Elo = " . $results['a'] . " WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']))
            {

            }
            else
            {
                ?>
                <script>alert('There was an error while entering winners(user) ranking...');</script>
                <?php
            }
            if(mysql_query("UPDATE users SET Elo = " . $results['b'] . " WHERE user_id=".$Loser_ID))
            {

            }
            else
            {
                ?>
                <script>alert('There was an error while entering losers(opp) ranking..');</script>
                <?php
            }

        }   
        elseif($oppscore > $userscore)
        {       
            $Loser_ID = $_SESSION['user'];
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE username = '".$opponent."'");
            $result = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die(mysql_error());
            $Winner_ID = $result['user_id'];

            //get rating from user table in database

            $query1 = mysql_query("SELECT Elo FROM users WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']);
            $result1 = mysql_fetch_array($query1) or die(mysql_error());
            $loserRating = $result1['Elo'];

            $query2 = mysql_query("SELECT Elo FROM users WHERE user_id=".$Loser_ID);
            $result2 = mysql_fetch_array($query2) or die(mysql_error());
            $winnerRating = $result1['Elo'];

            $rating = new Rating($winnerRating, $loserRating, 1, 0);            
            $results = $rating->getNewRatings();

            $results = $rating->getNewRatings();
            if(mysql_query("UPDATE users SET Elo = " . $results['b'] . " WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']))
            {

            }
            else
            {
                ?>
                <script>alert('There was an error while entering losers(user) ranking...');</script>
                <?php
            }
            if(mysql_query("UPDATE users SET Elo = " . $results['a'] . " WHERE user_id=".$Winner_ID))
            {

            }
            else
            {
                ?>
                <script>alert('There was an error while entering winners(opp) ranking...');</script>
                <?php
            }

        }
        if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO games(WinnerID,LoserID,PointsFor,PointsAgainst) VALUES('$Winner_ID','$Loser_ID','$userscore','$oppscore')"))
        {
            ?>
            <script>alert('Your scores were successfully entered');</script>
            <?php
        }
        else
        {
            ?>
            <script>alert('There was an error while entering your score...');</script>
            <?php
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ?>
        <script>alert('There cannot be a tie in ping pong, please re-enter your scores...');</script>
        <?php
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: So your actual question is how to get the loser to show up in your query that currently only shows the winner?

Comment: Can you show us an example of what your `SELECT` returns now, as well as what you would like it to return?

Comment: @Sean Exactly. It only displays information for the WinnerID, I believe, correct me if I'm wrong. My issue is that the points for and against don't add up. They would be equal. Same with wins and losses.

Comment: @DarwinvonCorax I added what the `SELECT` returns. Thanks for your help.

Comment: So the sum of the **Points For** column should equal the sum of the **Points Against** column?

Comment: Yes, that is my issue. Players will only be able to log scores against other users registered to the website, so all **Points For** should be equal to **Points Against**. Same with wins and losses. Thanks a lot by the way.

Comment: Negative @Strawberry

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query fails because it doesn't take into account the rows where the player loses. You can fix that by using [unions](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-union-keyword.htm). The following query should do what you want:

```
SELECT  username AS "Username",
    SUM(wins) AS "Wins",
    SUM(PF) AS "Points For",
    SUM(PA) AS "Points Against",
    elo AS "Ranking"
FROM (
    (SELECT users.user_ID,
            users.username AS username,
            COUNT(games.WinnerID) AS wins,
            SUM(games.PointsFor) AS PF,
            SUM(games.PointsAgainst) AS PA,
            users.Elo AS elo
    FROM users, games
    WHERE games.WinnerID = users.user_ID
    GROUP BY users.user_ID)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT users.user_ID,
        users.username AS username,
        0 AS wins,
        SUM(games.PointsAgainst) AS PF,
        SUM(games.PointsFor) AS PA,
        users.Elo AS elo
    FROM users, games
    WHERE games.LoserID = users.user_ID
    GROUP BY users.user_ID)
) AS t
GROUP BY username
ORDER BY user_ID;
```

Note that in the "losing query" the field `PointsAgainst` should be counter as the player's "points for" and vice-versa.

Comment: Thank you so much! I even figured out how to put the loss column in there thanks to you. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try it as an inner join, and get rid of the `MIN()` on the `username` column:

```
SELECT u.username, COUNT(g.WinnerID),
       SUM(g.PointsFor), SUM(g.PointsAgainst), u.Elo
  FROM users u, games g
  WHERE u.user_id = g.WinnerID
  GROUP BY u.username, u.Elo;
```

Also, before anyone else takes you to task, you should be using `mysqli` instead of `mysql` (or better yet, `PDO`) and you should be using prepared statements instead of dynamic SQL.

Comment: This still gets the same output as my `SELECT` statement above

Comment: Let's make sure your data is complete before we go too far down the rabbit hole. Run `SELECT SUM(PointsFor), SUM(PointsAgainst) FROM games;` and if that works, try `SELECT WinnerId, SUM(PointsFor), SUM(PointsAgainst) FROM games GROUP BY WinnerID;`

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
INSERT INTO games(WinnerID,LoserID,PointsFor,PointsAgainst) VALUES('$Winner_ID','$Loser_ID','$userscore','$oppscore')
```

query contains the `$userscore` and `$oppscore` values in a potentially wrong order. The `$Winner_ID` and `$Loser_ID` may change in your conditional processing, but `$userscore` and `$oppscore` are not similarly flipped at that time.

Also your conditional structure is in general unnecessarily verbose. It seems like you should be able to just determine the winner and loser ID and score first, and then do all your processing once instead of resorting to error-prone copy-paste duplication of near-identical code.